# How to set a custom prompt in pdb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdb

As mentioned in the title - how can the default `(Pdb)` prompt be changed to something else? There doesn't appear to be a built-in way of setting the prompt per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) or [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/658ff844963b68b420d663c188cd5fc78442db3f/Lib/pdb.py).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround could be to set it dynamically in `.pdbrc`, like

```py
!(lambda: exec('import gc, pdb; next(o for o in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(o, pdb.Pdb)).prompt = "pdb> "', {}))()
```

which results in the prompt "`pdb>`". This also avoids polluting the local scope.

Alternatively, use another debugger like [pdb++](https://pypi.org/project/pdbpp/) for which the prompt and other attributes can be configured (per [here](https://github.com/antocuni/pdb#configuration-and-customization)).